# Automapper: reusing created maps

Tags: c#, automapper

If for example I have something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo,FooDto>()
   .ForMemeber( ...;
```

and I have

```
class Bar
{
   public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

class BarDto
{
   public FooDto Foo { get; set; }
}
```

than I have to repeat the mapping logic for Foo to FooDto again:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Bar,BarDto>()
      .ForMemeber(...
```

At the moment I use Mapper.Map inside a ValueResolver but I think that there could be a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to re-do the Foo/FooDto mapping logic.  Any time AutoMapper finds the Foo/FooDto pair, whether it's in an array of values, dictionary, collection, child member or whatever, that Foo/FooDto configuration will be used.  AutoMapper doesn't care *where* the type pair is found.